# What is difference between >>> vs >>? in python console?

Tags: python

I am executing one script and when I open my console, it shows `>>?` in the console line. I have seen that actually it should be `>>>`. Can someone explain what is wrong with my console/script? How can I change from `>>?` to `>>>`?

Comment: This could help - http://pymotw.com/2/sys/interpreter.html#interactive-prompts

Comment: You will need to include more information. What do you mean by console, What OS, what script?

Comment: I am using python command line (Python 2.7.2 64 bit) in windows 8.1. I have one python script which opens a file and reads data from it.